# Is it possible to mock a system service in Android

Tags: android, mockito

all. I'm new to use Mockito:)

```
Context mockContext = mock(Context.class);
TelephonyManager mockTelephonyManager = mock(TelephonyManager.class);
when(mockTelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso()).thenReturn("CN");

when(mockContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).thenReturn(mockTelephonyManager);
```

the above won't work when espresso test trying to use the telephony, it still return the system network country ISO. any thoughts? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like any(Context.class) solved my issue. When passing context as parameters. Not sure why mocking context won't work.